# linear programming (is this doable?)

Tags: ds.algorithms, linear-programming

I have the LP formulation at the link below for the following problem:

[my lp formulation](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~btas/lpformulation.png)

Minimize:

- $\sum_{i=1}^{N_1} \sum_{j=1}^{N_2} x_{ij}$

Subject to:

- $\sum_{i=m}^{m+a-1} \sum_{j=n}^{n+b-1} x_{ij} \ge k$
- $x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$

where

- $\forall m, 1 \le m \le N_1 - a + 1 \wedge$
- $\forall n, 1 \le n \le N_2 - b + 1$

We have a $N_1 \times N_2$ grid. Each cell of the grid can have the
value either 0 or 1. Assume that we have $a \times b$ windows as
the subset of the $N_1 \times N_2$ grid where $a < N_1$ and $b < N_2$,
and we want to have at least $k$ of the cells in each window
have the value 1. We want to minimize the number of 
cells having the value 1.

$x_{ij}$, in the formulation, represents the cell at $i$th column
and $j$th row.

Actually, this problem is a reduction from the problem, 
Hitting Set.

Now, I want to add another set of constraints which guarantees that
the pairs that will be formed out of the cells (having value 1, and 
location $(i,j)$) of the $N_1 \times N_2$ grid
will have unique slope values. I've been thinking on this, but couldn't figure out if
it is doable or not using LP.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: is this a homework question? Also, the site supports LaTeX, why not just LaTeX the formulation instead of linking us?

Comment: I am not sure I see what does this question has to with theoretical computer science ?

Comment: this is out of scope for being too localized.

Answer (score 1):

BTW you have an IP. You'd have an LP if you relax the $x_{ij} \in \{0, 1\}$ constraint to $0\leq x_{ij} \leq 1$.

For your question: for two pairs of cells $\{(i, j), (i + u, j + v)\}$ and $\{(k, l), (k + u, l + v)\}$, you can add a constraint: $x_{ij} + x_{i + u, j + v} + x_{kl} + x_{k + u, l + v} \leq 3$. In the IP this should enforce your condition: it implies that for any two pairs of points "with the same slope", at least one point has value 0. There will be $O(N^3)$ such constraints, where $N = N_1 N_2$.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: corrected the mistake, the number of new constraints is $O(N_1^3 N_2^3)$ as you have one constraint for each set of integers $i, j, k, l, u, v$.